# When does [UIAlert show] actually happen?

Tags: ios

I'm stepping through some code in lldb, and I come across `[alert show]`. I step across it, nothing happens, then I continue and the alert pops up, presumably triggered sometime later. Just for curiosity's sake, when does that `show` message actually get sent to the operating system? What's really going on when I step over `[alert show]`? The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) doesn't address it.

Comment: Basically, when the UI thread returns to the dispatcher loop.

Comment: @HotLicks Nah, the **message send itself** happens immediately. It's just the rendering that's delayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIKit and core animation changes are processed and applied as part of the main run loop. When you call `[alert show]` the appropriate view hierarchy changes, frame changes, animations etc. are queued up in the system. When you return from your code the runloop will process these as part of the core animation transaction internals and you will see the changes on screen.